# Core Data fetch request uses a lot of memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, memory-management

I'm battling to understand the problem I'm having with Core Data and a simple fetch request:

I need to display some records and I execute these lines of code

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init]; 
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Venue"                                     
inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];

 NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"id_" ascending:YES]; 

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];  
[sortDescriptor release];
sortDescriptor = nil;

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors]; 
[sortDescriptors release];
sortDescriptors = nil;

[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
```

So far so good, but in Instruments I can see that before loading the records, my memory is 9mb, afterwards the memory jumps to 44mb (!!) and still there. But I want to release all the records from memory because I don't need them anymore. Did I miss something? I thought that Core Data was releasing the records after they aren't needed anymore. I tried to do a for-cycle to release every ManagedObject, but they are already +1 count, meaning they are soon to be released.

Comment: Sorry,forgot to mention is iOS

Comment: Try this: Run on simulator/instruments. Recreate to 44mb. Then "Force Memory Warning" in simulator and see if the memory is recovered as Core Data "faults" the managed objects.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't run on Simulator because some frameworks. I updated the code but no luck :(

 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Venue"];
  fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = NO;
  
  NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];

  NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];

  [moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];

  NSError *error;
  [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
  
  [moc reset];
  [moc release];
  [coordinator release];

Comment: 1. set fetch request to return objects as faults == YES. faults take less memory but will make access slower.

Comment: 2. Where are you storing the Managed objects returned from the execute request?

Comment: In this example nowhere, I created a venue.h/m class, added a "dealloc" method and I can see that each Managed Objects is deallocated correctly.

Fault = YES doens't change anything, I did it only for test.

Comment: @DigitalVanilla. I'm sorry I can't think of anything else to be helpful. In general the Managed Objects will fault out when required and are returned to you as auto released objects, so will dealloc when no longer referenced by your UI. I'm surprised you managed to get 44Mb allocated on a physical device. Its quite a lot. If you haven't had the watchdog bring you down due to excessive memory warnings I'd leave it alone for now and see how you get on. Are you sure instruments are telling you 44Mb; it seems like a hugh amount?

Comment: If the entity Venue is in a relationship with other entities, then perhaps look out for retain cycles that are preventing the objects from being released. Your example dosen't mention relatiobships so I'm assuming there isn't any for the entities in question. More info at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMemory.html

Comment: have no idea truly :( resetting the context and releasing it, it doesn't seems to do anything. NSZombies are disabled (I saw another post here with a guy that had the same my problem and it was the NSZombies as YES). Im calling every 2 seconds with a sleep(2); this method, destroying each time the object that contains all Core Data related methods, and every time the memory is filled with new MO, like the context never release its stack even when I reset, release and set as nil.

Comment: I do apologize Damien, yes Venue has a relationship as this:

venues > categories > chapters > city

but my question is: if I do a reset of the context, isn't the right way to destroy every relationship and free every connection to recall all the memory? One new note, I can see that the memory after calling 6 times the object and the method, it's always stable there. Means that something else keeps in the memory.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7361/discussion-between-digitalvanilla-and-damien)

Comment: ok, I found a clue: even if I dont fetch, but I just create the object the object that holds the core data objects (context,store..) and release it, I'll never be able to free the memory... there must be something else at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you no longer need your NSManagedObjects, you can manually turn them back into a `fault`. i.e. Remove them from the NSManagedObjectContext. Next time you want them, they will be loaded from the persistent store again.

I do this to conserve memory when I'm synchronising with a server and updating objects, but I don't need to use them immediately.

To re-fault, use this (and read the API Docs about it's usage)

```
- (void)refreshObject:(NSManagedObject *)object mergeChanges:(BOOL)flag
```

Comment: well, I tried everything but nothing works: NSZombie is disabled (as in this post https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3103423?start=0&tstart=0), also I added a block of Autorelease pool object and drained soon after the fetch line, I created a class object from the entity and in the dealloc method I placed a simple NSLog. I can see  that each of the records get's released as expected, the main object that hold the Core Data objects (context...) is released and the context resetted too and everything is gone, I still have my memory fileld with data that I can't release it for some reason.

Comment: So in the instrument Allocations, you can see trace what is using that memory? Try changing to Call Stack, and invert call tree, hide system libraries ... and see if it's anything in your code that is using the memory.

Comment: I uploaded the zip file of the test project www.digitalvanilla.com/test.zip

Comment: I've ran your app on iOS 5.0 simulator, and the live bytes is only 850KB... ?? Overall bytes is 80MB - but this is memory that includes objects that have been released and destroyed. Live bytes is what you should be concerned about.... where did you see 44MB?

Comment: 44mb was in the real app, now on Activity Monitor, Real Memory I can see 12mb. Did you run on the device? I heard Core Data behave different.

Comment: @bandejapaisa there is a test project, no real data here
db is empty

Comment: @DigitalVanilla try to use MagicalRecords framework 
https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord
You will have less and clean code

Comment: Just did the same on an iPhone 4S iOS 5.01, peaked at 7.5MB, live bytes 602KB, (overall bytes 80 MB). This looks fine to me.

Comment: sorry, i lost test.sqlite. i will test again

Comment: - (NSArray *)venues
{ 
 NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
 
 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Venue"]; 
 [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
           [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"id_" ascending:YES],
           nil]]; 
 
 
 NSArray *arr = [[moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] retain];
 NSLog(@"arr count %d", [arr count]); 
 return nil;
}
i used [retain] for result array to measure memory consumption
try this code without retaining result array, i have about 1MB overall

Answer (score 2):

you should release request
 [fetchRequest release];

Comment: I'm releasing it but nothing, memory still there.

Comment: some questions:
1. iOS device or Simulator?
2.What do you with fetched data later?
3. How many row is fetched?

Comment: . iOS
. right now I'm not doing anything with the fetched data, just trash everything
. around 1500 rows fetched

Comment: I uploaded the zip file of the test project www.digitalvanilla.com/test.zip